# When does the DataGridView get its value from a custom EditingControl?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, custom-controls

I have a need to host a `DateTimePicker` control in a `DataGridView` cell.  I have gotten this to work properly by deriving a class from `DataGridViewColumn`, another from `DataGridViewCell`, and a third which derives from `DateTimePicker` and implements `IDataGridViewEditingControl`.  Everything is working exactly as I'd like it to except for one small detail.

If the user selects to show seconds in the column then they are always displayed, but if the cell is edited any seconds that the user enters in the cell are truncated.  When I went in to try to track down the bug I realized that I'm actually not exactly sure how the the `DataGridViewCell` gets its value from the editing control.  I'm sure that if I could figure out where this is happening then I could figure out what my bug is.  So my question is.  How does the value of the editing control get back to the `DataGridViewCell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own problem, but will post my solution here just in case somebody has the same very frustrating issue in the future.  So if you have created a custom DataGridView column/cell/editing control and after editing your value is not correct then here is a work around.  Override the `DataGridViewCell.SetValue(int rowIndex, object value)` method.  I'll admit, I never found where the cell's value comes from, but I did find that it gets passed through here.  From here I could still get access to the editing control and from there I could get the proper value instead of the strange value that I was getting.  From there you can take the value that you really need and pass it through `base.SetValue(rowIndex, newVal);` and you're value will be set properly.

I honestly don't understand why Microsoft  didn't have `IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetValue()` defined in the interface, but they don't, so this is the workaround.